# Ionic 5 Virtual scroll creates blank space instead of new item

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular8

[image: this is the output problem image]

I am trying to render the list using ion-virtual-scroll but when I update the list dynamically it doesn't show the new item and create blank space but when I inspect the scroll that item is present in the list with this CSS property "    transform: translate3d(0px, -9999px, 0px); "

```
   <ion-col size="12" size-sm="8" offset-sm="2" class="ion-text-center">
    <ion-virtual-scroll [items]="listedLoadedPlaces"

    >
      <ion-item

        [routerLink]="place.id"
        detail
        *virtualItem="let place"
      >
        <ion-thumbnail slot="start">
          <ion-img [src]="place.imageUrl"></ion-img>
        </ion-thumbnail>
        <ion-label>
          <h2>{{place.title}}</h2>
          <p>{{place.description}}</p>
        </ion-label>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-virtual-scroll>
  </ion-col>
```

Answer (score 2):

Anyone encountering this or a similar issue may want to try running `checkRange` or `checkEnd` these apis provided by the `IonVirtualScroll` mark either the last item or a specified item as dirty to trigger a fresh render of that item.

IN an ionic angular project it will look something like this.

```
template: <ion-virtual-scroll #listedLoadedPlacesScroll [items]="listedLoadedPlaces">
           <ion-item........

component:
  @ViewChild('#listedLoadedPlacesScroll', null) listedLoadedPlacesScroll: IonVirtualScroll;

.....
functionToUpdateList(): void {
   this.listedLoadedPlaces.push(newItem);
   this.listedLoadedPlacesScroll.checkEnd();
}
```

If you just needed to update a specific item that wasnt the last one in the source data array, you will use `checkRange`

```
template: <ion-item
        [routerLink]="place.id"
        detail
        *virtualItem="let place; let index = index;"
        (click)="doSomething(place, index)"
      >

component:
    doSomething(place, index): void {
      ..do something to place...
      this.listedLoadedPlacesScroll.checkRange(index, 1);
}
```

In `checkRange` you instruct the IonVirtualScroll element to mark the item at the index as dirty, the second param is `len` for `length`,  it is how many items including the current item to mark as dirty. SO len = 3 means index, index + 1, index + 2 items at those positions will be marked dirty and subjected to a fresh render.

I had one issue where changing an item in view required a change to an item out of view the solution was to mark all the items as dirty `checkRange(0, items.length)`, in elegant perhaps but it works as desired now.

Comment: have you considered doing checkRange on each index instead?